# How to change authorization denied page in ASP NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

Currently when using authentication, the framework will redirect an unauthorized request back to a login page even when the user is already logged in rather than show an 'access denied' page or use the standard HTTP response code for access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil Haack did a good blog post on this just the other week

[Prevent Forms Authentication Login Page Redirect When You Don’t Want It](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx)

It's basicly a short coming of the (current) .Net architecture,
He suggests a few options to get around this, normally I'd put some code here rather than just a link, but he explains is in some good detail and external links.